# kaggle_metadata = pd.read_csv(f'{file_dir}movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False) ratings = pd.read_csv(f'{file_dir}ratings.csv')

Tags: pandas, csv

when i Run the code I get this error, how can I fix it?

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12432/2876068499.py in 
----> 1 kaggle_metadata = pd.read_csv(f'{file_dir}movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False)
2 ratings = pd.read_csv(f'{file_dir}ratings.csv')

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
312
313         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
585
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
587
588

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is in the contents of `file_dir` variable.

Try `print(f"{file_dir}movies_metadata.csv")`, add the output to your question and see what goes wrong. It might be one of these:

- The path is relative, but the program is executed from another directory (`file_dir` starts with a folder name)
- File path starts in a wrong place (disk root instead of home folder or the other way around)
- `file_dir` has no slash at the end and this leads to the wrong file name
- The path is completely wrong